# Automatically add header and footer every time something is to be printed in C# WinFormsApp

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, printdocument, spooler

Please bear with me...

My goal is to finish building a desktop application that runs in the background that puts header and footer to everything that is to be printed.

It is written as a c# WinFormsApp that has an event trigger every time something is to be printed. It would then stop the print job temporarily and get it from the spooler to add header and footer to it then proceeds to printing afterwards...
No user intervention is needed. This makes sure that any printout will get to have a header and footer.
The libraries I have found are mostly from old posts.
The most recent one is the one that uses printDocument.

I don't have any functional code yet since I don't have much background with desktop stuff. (WebDev)

Any pointers will do...

P.S.: I also tried searching github already if there is already an existing project there but no luck.

The closest existing application I got with matching features was named printLimit with a 30-day trial period.

Comment: Check if the utilities that accompany the printer driver already support this feature. For example, the following EPSON and RICOH drivers already have this feature built-in:
https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd54608/source/printers/source/printing_software/windows_fy13/reference/header_footer_settings_windows_bus_wf3012.html
https://manuals.ricoh.com/driver/pcl6v4/help/en/HTMLFILE/idh_how_header.htm

Comment: @NickPapadiochos yep, already considered that one but we have many printer brands being used. And currently, we are searching for a one-solution-for-all type of action. We also need to ba able to insert an image(a logo for example). Thanks for the input though... 